# Optimal XPath Query for processing the sample HTML fragment

Tags: xpath

I have a feed that outputs HTML. The following segment is part of the output

```
<div class="leftnav">
    <table border="0" cols="2">

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="topline"><span style="font-size: 1px">&nbsp;</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><span class="bold">Article Cat1 </span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" colspan="2">
               ArticleTitle1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="20"></td>
            <td class="date">
                ArticleLink1
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="topline"><span style="font-size: 1px">&nbsp;</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><span class="bold">Article Cat2 </span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="date" colspan="2">
               ArticleTitle2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="20"></td>
            <td class="date">
                ArticleLink2
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to process above segment using XPATH so that output looks like this

> Article Cat1
>                  ArticleTitle1
>                                 ArticleLink1 Article Cat2
>                  ArticleTitle2
>                                  ArticleLink2

What is the optimal XPATH that will produce the desired output? I tried `//div[@class="leftnav"]/table/tr` but this gives all the TR elements. I want to skip the first TR element so that I can get the output in the format I described above.

Answer (score 0):

```
//div[@class="leftnav"]/table/tr[position() > 1]
```

Try the above

Answer (score 0):

Stupid simple way:

```
substring-after(normalize-space(string(//*:div)), normalize-space(string(//*:div/*:table/*[1])))
```

Result: "Article Cat1 ArticleTitle1 ArticleLink1 nbsp Article Cat2 ArticleTitle2 ArticleLink2"

I don't know why, but (`position() > 1`) doesn't work in my environment, so I've used strings instead.

Comment: This is XPath 2.0 only, most implementations only support XPath 1.0. Why are you omitting a namespace that is not even given?